# How to do a performant iteration over 2 lists in the context of the question body?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

hypothesis:

We have 2 lists of different sizes.

- List A contains 100 items.
- List B contains 1000000 items.

Both Lists are of type `List<ObjectName>`. `ObjectName` contains `int Id` and `string Name`.

List A is populated with Ids and Names.
List b is populated only with Ids,String.Empty.

Both Lists can be populated with duplicate Ids.
The ids are primary keys of same Entity across both lists.
Problem:
How to iterate efficiently (not foreach) over the two lists, so that List B is populated with the Name property from List A.

My take:
The lists are not sorted by id, but they can be sorted by id. My problem is not that it did not work, it did, but i believe i will have performance issues. I did:

```
 foreach (var userIdName in userIdNames)
            {
                foreach (var logItem in logList)
                {
                    if (userIdName.Id == logItem.UserId)
                    {
                        logItem.UserName = userIdName.Name;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I thought about Paralel.Foreach, but i am not so knowledgeable in that. Any advice?

Comment: Are your lists sorted by id?

Comment: You should try first and tell us what didn't work. Let try the linq parallel iteration and let us know

Comment: *"How to iterate efficiently (not foreach)"* What's wrong with `foreach` ? Are you getting performance issues?

Comment: *"Both Lists can be populated with duplicate Ids"* This is confusing. Can List A contains duplicates ids? If so, which one should be used in B?

Comment: You can work with [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) too, the key being the id, the value being the name. Access complexity is O(1)

Comment: The shown code is unreadable in comments. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64676747/edit) your question if you want to add content

Comment: the List of Id and Names represents an nhibernate detached criteria result. I wished i could use dictionaries.

Comment: *i believe i will have performance issues* you don't know this unless you measure it. This smells of premature optimisation. that is O(n2) but given the small numbers of items in each array here I'd still expect it to complete in a very short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a value of each item in `ListB` needs to be set, you have no option but to iterate over that list.

To optimise the operation, you need to convert `ListA` into a structure that has `O(1)` access, to give an overall complexity of `O(n)`, with `n` being the length of `ListB`.

As `ListA` is small, using an in-memory lookup shouldn't be a problem:

```
var lookup = userIdNames.ToLookup(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
foreach (var logItem in logList)
{
    logItem.UserName = lookup[logItem.UserId].FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This assumes that items in `userIdNames` with duplicate `Id`'s always have the same `Name`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Johnathan, I had to update a bit the lookup. It was trying to pass the Type Model into a string. logItem.UserName = lookup[logItem.UserId].Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @alin Yes that would work, or use the overload of `ToLookup` that accepts an element selector: `userIdNames.ToLookup(x => x.Id, x => x.Name)`.